# Restart Gridgain Server without data loss and wal folder corrupted

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, ignite, gridgain

I have a Gridgain server deployed in Google Kubernetes engine with persistence enable. Server start with default configurations. I need to change walMode as FSYNC. But it is not possible because WAL directory given access denied exception. Then I delete wal and walArchive PersistenceVolumeClaim object and try to restart it. But it given error.

Is there any way to start GridGain server with my existing data. Now wal and walArchive directories are deleted and created new one.

Other than that if any reason wal and walArchive data corrupt any reason have any way to safely start Gridgain server without any data loss.

Answer (score 1):

Referring [1] and [2] found the solution.

As the answer 1 of [1]

***The folder located at $IGNITE_HOME/work/db/$NODE_UUID/cp has to be cleaned
up. After this, node should start in normal way.***

need to delete "cp" folder if wal and walArchive folders are delete. If application running in Kubernetes and server node not cannot start following [2] create new pod with mounting data folder. Then exec to it and delete "cp" folder.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: task-pv-pod
  namespace: gridgain
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: task-pv-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: work-vol-gridgain-cluster-2 # persistent volume claim  
  containers:
    - name: task-pv-container
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: "http-server"
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/gridgain/" # Mount to data folder
          name: task-pv-storage
```

Then server start without errors.

[1]. http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Is-there-any-way-to-force-recover-the-cluster-copying-running-cluster-datastore-td28399.html

[2]. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/